# Migrating data from custom mysql to wordpress tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have written a script to migrate data from a custom legacy system database (mysql) and update the wordpress database with those values. The trouble is that I update the table but the change does not show up in the admin panel - the fields are still blank.

Example: I copy accessibility options like "wheelchair" from the old DB table and insert it as "serialized" data in wordpress (as that is the required format).

I then display the post with the accessibility options in it and the option remains blank even though the new value is in the DB.

I tried updating the accessibility from the wordpress admin panel and compared the value I was inserting into the database table (from the old system) with the update made by wordpress itself and the values are identical.

The only thing I can think of is that the data is cached somewhere and if I update using wordpress the value is pulled in. If I update using the direct DB update then that new value is ignored or a cached version is shown that prevents the new value showing.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to make the DB update stick and display in the post?

Code example

```
    // Get a list of accessibility options selected in xxx
    $querystr = "select * from accessibility_to_event where site_id = 
    $site_id and event_id = $event->meta_value";
    $access = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

    $access_array = array();
    foreach ($access as $acid){
        $accessname = $accesslist[$acid->accessibility_id];
    $access_array[] = $accessname;
    }

    if (empty($access_array)) continue;

    $querystr = "select * from ".$prefix."xxx_eventmeta where meta_key = 
    '_xxx_event_data' and xxx_event_id = $event->xxx_event_id";
    $eventmeta = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

    $eventmeta = unserialize($eventmeta[0]->meta_value);
    $eventmeta = unserialize($eventmeta);
    $eventmeta['_custom_accessibility'] = $access_array;        
    $eventmeta = serialize($eventmeta);
    $eventmeta = serialize($eventmeta);

    // Save the new meta_value values
    $querystr = "update ".$prefix."xxx_eventmeta set meta_value = 
   '$eventmeta' where meta_key = '_xxx_event_data' and xxx_event_id = 
    $event->xxx_event_id";
    $eventmeta = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Comment: 1 - please show some code example . 2 - what do you mean  by `accessibility options`

Comment: accessibility options are like "wheelchair access", "closed caption" etc.

Comment: Are these `options` technically `post_meta` ? and if so , do they have underscores `_` in front of the name ?

Comment: Yes they do have underscores and they are custom post meta.

Comment: Underscore post_meta is hidden. either remove the underscore or test to retrieve it in another way ( not via interface ) e.g.  `get_post_meta()`

Comment: The problem with what you suggest is that the wordpress system stores the meta value with an underscore and that displays just fine in the admin panel. The data created by wordpress and the data created by the DB update are identical. So there must be something else going on.

Comment: Wordpress can store the values both with underscore or not . the difference is that when you use underscore , the values are hidden from the `post_meta` UI in the post admin screen. where are you trying to "update" it or to "pull" it code wise ?